# Angular Compomente Personalizado emitEvent: false

Tags: angular

Eu preciso que no meu componente personalizado quando efetue um atribuição de valor ele não emita eventos, quando eu setar isso no patchValue ou setValue.

patchValue  **{ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false }**

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-validation-emit-event-schoolofne-am3c4x)

ao setar o valor inicial ele dispara o `this.onChangeCallback(v)`

```
set value(v: any) {
   this.onChangeCallback(v);
}

onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = () => {};
```

ignorando o **emitEvent: false**

Answer (score 1):

Após o carregamento do seu formulário é emitido um único evento para o `lastName` que escreve uma mensagem no console:

```
event.last.name Reis
```

Isto ocorre porque seu segundo input é um componente customizado (`app-input-text`) que implementa o `ControlValueAccessor`. O problema é que a função que é passada como parâmetro pelo framework no método `writeValue` não recebe o segundo parâmetro do método `this.form.patchValue`. Inclusive há uma questão aberta sobre este comportamento [neste link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20230).

Você poderia tentar um workaround utilizando uma variável booleana por exemplo, ou alterar seu código de modo a não precisar deste recurso.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido o problema era no writeValue

troquei

```
writeValue(v: any): void {
  this.value = v;
}
```

por

```
writeValue(v: any): void {
 if (v !== this.innerValue) {
   this.innerValue = v;
 }
}
```